# Prove that is $\bar{f}g$ is analytic then $f$ is constant or...?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help with the following exercise:

Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions on a region $G$ such that $\bar{f}g$ is analytic then $f$ is constant or $g\equiv0$

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried applying the CR-equations? That's holomorphic, though, and not analytic, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use the fact that a function $f$ is analytic iff 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} f = 0.
\end{align}

Suppose $\bar f g$ is analytic, which means
\begin{align}
0=\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z} (\bar f g) = \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \bar z}g+ \bar f\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} = \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}g+ \bar f\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}.
\end{align}

Since $g$ is analytic, then $\partial_{\bar z} g = 0$ which means
\begin{align}
0 = \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}g \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0 \ \text{ or } \ \ g=0.
\end{align} 
In the former case, we have $f$ is an analytic function such that the complex derivative vanishes, then $f$ must be constant.

Comment: ... or $g=0{}$.

Comment: You need to argue a little bit more. In general, the product of two functions may be the zero function, even though neither of the factors are.

Comment: They are analytic.